# Adding column to wpex_users

Tags: php, database

So I am trying to add a column to wpex_users. For some reason I cannot. This is my query:

`ALTER TABLE wpex_users ADD nametest VARCHAR(200);`

It gives me the error that my standard value is wrong. It is on NULL. I do not know what to do. I really need this new column.

Do you know the query I need to add a new column? I write the query in PHPMyAdmin.

Comment: You should not add columns to WordPress tables, when you update WP will remove the column and all that data will be erased, it is extremely bad practice, and dangerous

Answer (score 0):

You should **never** modify the WP core tables, all your changes will be undone and the data lost the next time WP updates its table schema.

Instead, if you want to store more data on a user, do what other people do and use user meta:

- `update_user_meta`
- `get_user_meta`
- `add_user_meta`
- `delete_user_meta`

You can even query for it with `WP_User_Query`.

Otherwise, by adding custom columns, you'll have to write a tonne of SQL code from scratch, and risk major data loss.

Comment: But I cannot add a column with those. I want to add a new column to the wpex_users.

Comment: **You should never add new columns to WP core tables, you will lose all your data when you update**, do not add columns to the user table, use user meta

Comment: I could do a join as well. That seems better

Comment: What are you doing exactly that necessitates this? Are you trying to write raw SQL queries for users and don't know how to query on the user meta field so you're trying to add a column to the user table? Is there a reason you don't just use `WP_User_Query` with PHP? Keep in mind that what's in the database won't account for plugins filters and hooks

Comment: Nevermind, I am clearly working with a many to many relationship here. I know how to solve this now